# To check the latest commits from Current and Main Branch using PowerShell Script in AzureDevops

Tags: git, azure, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0

When the developers start their work by creating their own feature branch and make their changes as per the requirement, I want to check and compare the latest commits from their feature branch with the Release Branch (which is created based on Main Branch). So, I have developed a PowerShell Script to check and compare the latest commits (check and compares the files) and also wanted to check if there are any zip file changes made, if so then it would extract and check the files which are modified and list the files as an output.
I tried to incorporate in the AzureDevops, where my PowerShell script is unable to fetch the release branch in the first place. Could you please assist me on what make it cause the issue. Please find my script for your reference.

```
# Fetch the latest changes from the remote repository
git fetch

# Get the current branch name
$currentBranch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

# Specify the release branch name
$releaseBranch = "release"

# Get the latest commit on the release branch
$latestReleaseCommit = git rev-list -n 1 $releaseBranch

# Get the latest commit on the current branch
$latestCurrentCommit = git rev-list -n 1 $currentBranch

# Get the list of zip files changed in the latest release commit
$releaseFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $latestReleaseCommit -- "*.zip"

# Get the list of zip files changed in the latest current commit
$currentFiles = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $latestCurrentCommit -- "*.zip"

# Flag to track if any zip files or their contents have changed
$hasChanged = $false

# Extract and check the contents of zip files
foreach ($zipFile in $currentFiles) {
    # Check if the zip file is in the list of zip files changed in the latest release commit
    $isZipFileChangedOnRelease = $releaseFiles -contains $zipFile

    # Check if the zip file has changed between release and current branches
    if ($isZipFileChangedOnRelease) {
        Write-Host "Zip file $zipFile has changed between release and current branches."
        
        # Extract the zip file to a temporary directory
        $tempDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() | Split-Path -Parent
        Expand-Archive -Path $zipFile -DestinationPath $tempDirectory -Force

        # Get the list of files extracted from the zip file
        $extractedFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempDirectory -File -Recurse

        # Check the extracted files for changes
        foreach ($extractedFile in $extractedFiles) {
            # Check if the extracted file exists in the release branch
            $isExtractedFileChangedOnRelease = $releaseFiles -contains $extractedFile.FullName

            # Check if the extracted file has changed between release and current branches
            if ($isExtractedFileChangedOnRelease) {
                $hasChanged = $true
                Write-Host "File $($extractedFile.FullName) extracted from $zipFile has changed between release and current branches."
            }
        }

        # Clean up the temporary directory
        Remove-Item -Path $tempDirectory -Force -Recurse
    }
}

# If any zip files or their contents have changed, fail the merge or build process
if ($hasChanged) {
    Write-Host "Error: Some zip files or their contents have changed between release and current branches."
    exit 1 # Exit with a non-zero exit code to indicate failure
} else {
    Write-Host "No zip files or their contents have changed between release and current branches. Proceeding with merge or build."
    exit 0 # Exit with a zero exit code to indicate success
}
```